# Open subitems of Flyoutmenu to the bottom

Tags: drop-down-menu, navbar, flyout, bootsfaces

I created a navBar with a Flyoutmenu inside and inside of that is a dropMenu with two subitems, so that I'm able to see the subitems when I'm just moving the mouse over it. The tricky thing is that the subitems are opened to the right side and hiding some other navLinks.
What I really would like to have is the subitems open to the bottom. Does anyone of you know what I have to add to the Flyoutmenu? I didn't find the correct option...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the documentation specifies that the subitems fly out to the right so i am not sure it is possible at the moment.  it may be possible to submit a feature request.  if it is simple tweak to the component it might make the next release? https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues

Comment: I'm almost sure you can achieve this with some CSS magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a little CSS snippet:

```
<style>
  .downwards .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
<b:flyOutMenu width="50px" styleClass="downwards">
      ...
</b:flyOutMenu>
```